# Storing session variables

Tags: django, session

I have four session variables--

```
location = request.session['location']
computer = request.session['computer']
phone = request.session['phone']
hobby = request.session['hobby']
```

I have several view functions that need to use these variables. Is there a way I can store these variables in a separate function and call them from the other functions? If so, how would I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understand? You can call session variables from wherever the **request** is available i.e. your views

```
def some_view(request):
    var1 = request.session.get('location', False)
    if var1:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

see more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#examples

---

From your comment:

```
getting_started_step_one(request)
```

This function is being passed request as a parameter, and therefore has access to all of request's variables. One of these variables/objects is **session**, and this session object in turn has access to the variables you are looking for (username, location etc..). So all you have to do is:

```
def getting_started_step_one(request):
    location = request.session.get("location", False)
```